# Decided to work smart by creating a JS to link to multiple HTML pages but on doing so a button doesn't seem to work. can't seem to understand why

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

**HTML CODE** (index.html)

```
<html>
  <div id="mode"></div>
  <script src="/js/install.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/create.js"></script>
</html>
```

`create.js` function to create an Install button

```
<html>
  <div id="mode"></div>
  <script src="/js/install.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/create.js"></script>
</html>
```

This specific line doesn't seem to trigger after the `button` is clicked but it would when simply written manually.

**(create.js)**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  var f = document.createElement("A");
  f.id = "m6";
  f.className =
    "add-button waves-effect red waves-light btn white-text right install";
  f.textContent = "INSTALL APP";
  document.getElementById("m4").appendChild(f);
});
```

This File doesn't seem to trigger when using `create.j`s to create the code but if done manually functions as should.

**(install.js)**

```
let deferredPrompt;
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");
addBtn.style.display = "none";
const addTxt = document.querySelector(".add-text");
addTxt.style.display = "none";

window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
  addBtn.style.display = "block";
  addTxt.style.display = "block";

  addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    addBtn.style.display = "none";
    addTxt.style.display = "none";
    // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === "accepted") {
        console.log("User accepted the A2HS prompt");
      } else {
        console.log("User dismissed the A2HS prompt");
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  });
});
```

Would deeply be grateful to anyone that can help with this.

Comment: I don't see `#m4` in your html

Comment: Hey im sorry for the very bad upload but i figured it out. Upon creation the install JS file does not trigger because it probably couldn't find the class because it wasn't created yet so with an  addEventListener('load',(e) => {});   the method gets re-triggered upon runtime with now the page already loaded with all its elements the class can be found and the function can run.

Comment: Yes your question also reminds me that i need to add //comments to my code for better understanding the .#m4 is the line just before the line of code you see it appends itself to it so as belong to that particular tag. eg <div id="m5"><div id="m4"></div></div>